# Using an include directory with SNMP (snmpd.conf)

Tags: configuration, snmpd

I'm having to add a number of `extend` directives to `snmpd.conf`, and each of the `extend`s are actually apart of various monitoring groups.  It makes a lot of sense to collect each group into a single file and then just add `include` somewhere in `snmpd.conf` but for the life of me I can't determine if there actually *is* an `include` directive (I think the answer is no) or how to use configuration file discovery (i.e., search and load configuration files in various directories).

Comment: I don't see anything. I'd use [puppetlabs/concat](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/concat) or something similar for something like this.

Comment: Unfortunately due to Puppet's feature of overwriting things when you least expect it, that isn't an option.  I'm pretty amazed that a tool like this doesn't have such a basic feature.

Answer (score 6):

In **RHEL** there're two configuration options, according to "man snmp_config", added in BZ#917816 enhancement.

```
# include site specific config
includeFile site.conf

# include a all *.conf files in a directory
includeDir /etc/snmp/config.d
```

Comment: Added in CentOS 6.5 https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.5_Technical_Notes/net-snmp.html